# share variables in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to share variables from `tkinter` class to the global code,
I have a `tkinter` gui in which I insert data and once closed the `tkinter` form I would like the code to print this data, but the code doesn't take the data I entered,and returns another value.

this is the code:

```
class App:

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.username = None
        self.frame1 = tk.LabelFrame (master, text="Instagram")
        self.frame1.pack ()
        self.dict = {'':[], 'Scienza': ['Nasa', '2', '3'],
                    'Moda': ['vladislavkirillov', 'barengo1', 'vittorio__badia'],
                    'Dunk Page': ['stupidpikachu', 'nascecresceignora', 'the_fucking_dank']}

        self.categoria_pagina = tk.StringVar()
        self.pagina_preimpostata = tk.StringVar()
        self.username1 = tk.StringVar()
        self.password = tk.StringVar()
        self.pagina_tua = tk.StringVar()
        self.commento1 = tk.StringVar()

        Entry (self.frame1, textvariable=self.username1, bg="white").grid (column=1, row=2, sticky=tk.W)

        Entry (self.frame1, textvariable=self.password, bg="white").grid (column=1, row=3, sticky=tk.W)

        Entry (self.frame1, textvariable=self.pagina_tua, bg="white").grid (column=1, row=4, sticky=tk.W)

        self.categoria_pagina.trace('w', self.updateoptions)

        self.optionmenu_a = ttk.OptionMenu(self.frame1, self.categoria_pagina, *self.dict.keys())
        self.categoria_pagina.set("Scienza")
        self.optionmenu_a.grid(row = 7, column = 1)

        self.optionmenu_b = ttk.OptionMenu(self.frame1, self.pagina_preimpostata, '')
        self.optionmenu_b.grid(row = 8, column = 1)


        self.variable_c = tk.StringVar ()
        self.variable_d = tk.StringVar ()


    def updateoptions(self, *args):
        countries = self.dict[self.categoria_pagina.get()]
        self.pagina_preimpostata.set(countries[0])
        menu = self.optionmenu_b['menu']
        menu.delete(0, 'end')
        for country in countries:
            menu.add_command(label=country, command=lambda country=country: self.pagina_preimpostata.set(country))


        categoria = self.categoria_pagina.get()
        pagina_preimpostata_stringa = self.pagina_preimpostata.get()
        username= self.username1.get()
        password= self.password.get()
        pagina_tua=self.pagina_tua.get()

    root = tk.Tk()

    app = App(root)

    root.mainloop()

    print(app.username)
```

it returns value None in place of the value that I insert in the `tkinter` gui

Comment: The error is clear , what is `username`?

Comment: `username= self.username1.get ()` why a space ? is this a typo ?

Comment: no ,without space. the problem is that the code doesn't recognize the variable when i exit from the tkinter gui. If i try to print the variable adding the command `print(username)` to a button in the tkinter gui it works

Comment: _"but the code doesn't take the data I entered,and give me and error."_ - what's the error?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when you do below in your code

```
username= self.username1.get()
```

Python creates a local variable in the scope of the function and when the function ends the variable is no longer there. So you have multiple was to solved this.

One is to define `username` in `__init__` of `App`

```
self.username = None
```

And in your function use

```
self.username = self.username1.get()
```

And in later you can use `print(app.username)`

Another option is to use global variables (NOT RECOMMENDED)

```
username = None

class App
.....
    global username
    username= self.username1.get()

....

print(username)
```

Comment: i tried to do as u said , i declared `self.username=None`  in `__init__` but whe i tried to do `print(app.username)` it returns value ` None` and not the value that i insert in the tkinter gui. With the global variable it works but if u said that it's not recommended i would like to find another way

Comment: Can you make sure your `updateoptions` is actually being called? Also please update complete code with import statements so one can debug

Comment: ye thanks it works, but do you have an idea of why it doesn't work with `print(app.username)`?

Comment: Because `updateoptions` is call when you have `self.categoria_pagina.trace('w', self.updateoptions)` and not after that. You want values after closing of the form